# itext7 pdfstream not compressed

Tags: c#, stream, compression, itext7, pdfa

I am trying to include an xml file into a pdf/a2 using itext7 and c#.

The xml has to be included into pdf names tree.

I was finally able to do it, the xml stream seems to be in the right names tree position.

There is still a problem, the stream has suppose to be compressed but is not, viewing the output pdf in a notepad you see the plain text.

It seems that the itext7 PdfStream is not able to do it, or at least, I am not able to compress it even setting compressionleve=9 - stream.SetCompressionLevel(9) in my code.

Anyone has a clue on how to do it.

Thank you very much.

Mauro

Here is my code:

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Pdfa;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PdfXml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pdfIn = "\\xfar\\pdfin.pdf";
            string pdfOut = "\\xfar\\pdfoutU.pdf";
            string cdaIn = "\\xfar\\cda.xml";
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(cdaIn);
                var content = new StringBuilder();
                string line;
                while (Reader.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    line = Reader.ReadLine();
                    content.AppendLine(line);
                }
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content.ToString());             
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfIn), new PdfWriter(pdfOut));            
                PdfStream stream = new PdfStream();;
                PdfNameTree nameTree1 = pdfDoc.GetCatalog().GetNameTree(new PdfName("XFAResource"));
                stream.SetCompressionLevel(9);
                stream.SetData(bytes, true);
                stream.Put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.FlateDecode);
                nameTree1.AddEntry("dataset", stream);
                nameTree1.BuildTree();
                nameTree1.SetModified();
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
                }                
              pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: compressionLevel can also be set on PdfWriter. Can you try ?

Comment: You set the filter `PdfName.FlateDecode`. Thus, you claim that the data already is compressed.

Comment: Thank you very much
After removing the set filter line the output stream is now compressed as expected